# Redundant network connections (using switches without link aggregation support)

Tags: switch, windows-10, redundancy

I need to connect two Windows 10 PCs together via Ethernet. They will be connected in series through two managed switches (Microchip KSZ9897). Each PC has two Intel NICs.
I need the links to be redundant so that communication between the two PCs are kept up if any one cable is damaged/disconnected. Throughput is minimal so I don’t care about increasing bandwidth.
I have looked into link aggregation, but it seems that the switches used must support 802.3ad/802.1ax in order for this to work. The KSZ9897 does not support link aggregation and I am unable to use another switch. However, KSZ9897 does support Rapid STP.

Intel has some SW (Intel ANS) that can team NICs that I maybe could use, but Windows 10 also has NetSwitchTeam using PowerShell.

What are my options for implementing redundancy, when the switches used do not support link aggregation?

In Windows Server, switch independent teaming exists, but I am not aware that this exists for Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Native NIC Teaming is not oficially supported in client OS (Windows 10). Proof  - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/504864ee-abad-49e0-9e6a-4a817e21e3d6 (comment of AdamRudell[MSFT])

If you have compatible Intel NICs, you may ANS with SFT mode.

Comment: That's a good point, I only really use server OS's so forgot that

Comment: I am aware that NIC teaming isn’t native to Windows 10, and that LBFO is Windows Server only. But maybe NetSwitchTeam can be used via PowerShell? I have seen this states several places online, e.g.: https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/win-10-nic-teaming-with-new-netswitchteam-command.28998/? If not Intel ANS could be the way to go. But I guess spanking tree is required for the switches, but I am unsure if the NICs in the PC and the switch with spanning tree can agree that the two interfaces are a one link. Should spanning tree be disabled on the switch ports connected to the PC?

Answer (score 0):

If your switches aren't aware of each other then I'd strongly suggest you use a simple active-standby setup within Windows Teaming to give you the resilience you need - it's extremely well understood, used and tested, easy to setup too!